# Maven and Shared Libraries

Tags: eclipse, maven, shared-libraries

I'm asking about the approach to deal with Shared Libraries In maven project
Currently we are working on many Java EE projects, having some internal-developed shared libraries (Wars) installed on Weblogic application server
Is it bad approach to add those shared libraries to the project through eclipse class-path as we are working on eclipse IDE, if so what is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, since you are using Maven, you should just be able to turn these shared WAR files into Maven artefacts, and add them as dependencies to your main WAR file.

Since you won't want to put those WAR files into a public repository, and you don't want to build them yourself, you need a group-level or organization-level Maven repository in which shared libraries and other useful things can be stored.  (We use Artifactory ... but there are other products that fill the same niche.)

Answer (score 1):

I think install [archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/) in your company network and deploy all war/jar that. See  [Maven Deploy Plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html) for details. Use that repository as one of repositories.

See [Maven Repository Manager Feature Matrix](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+Repository+Manager+Feature+Matrix) for comparison.